# Code To Delete Rows By Date Expired Field In MySql Using Triggers?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I need to delete rows from a MySql database whenever a field within any row has passed its expiry date, in this case it is older than today.
I am on a shared hosting account with events disabled & permissions denied for cronjobs.
My host has given permission to do this with a Trigger but I am usure what code to use (even after googling).
Any example codes anyone can share?
Also, what goes in the definition box & what goes in the definer box?

Comment: A trigger runs when a statement runs, not at a scheduled time. You still need a cron job or some other trigger to invoke it. How many rows are we talking about here?

Comment: It will probably go up to about 500 rows in total to check with any number to be deleted dependent on expiry date.

Answer (score 2):

Are you allowed to create MySQL events? Then you can use something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT removeold_hourly
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 HOUR
    COMMENT 'Remove items before today'
    DO
      DELETE FROM mytable WHERE col < CURDATE();
```

This will delete all rows from mytable where col < today. This check will be done every hour.

Comment: Hi Niels, thanks for the reply. According to my host Events are disabled.....They have allowed me to use a trigger to delete the expired rows....so I just need to know what to put into the 'Definition' box & the 'Definer' box.....Also i want it to occur once a day at midnight.

Comment: With only triggers you can't do it. You can check it on insert of other rows. So if you have a lot of inserts, or an update (user count) or something. You can execute a query to delete the old rows.

Answer (score 0):

The definition box should contain the SQL query you intend to trigger.
`DELETE FROM mytable where col < CURDATE()`

The definer box specifies

> the MySQL account to be used when checking access privileges at
> trigger activation time. If a user value is given, it should be a
> MySQL account specified as 'user_name'@'host_name' (the same format
> used in the GRANT statement), CURRENT_USER, or CURRENT_USER(). The
> default DEFINER value is the user who executes the CREATE TRIGGER
> statement. This is the same as specifying DEFINER = CURRENT_USER
> explicitly.

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php